# Suppose ${a_n}$ converges to $a$ and that $|a|<1$. Prove that the sequence ${(a_n)^n}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know $\{a_n^n\}$ can be written as $\{a_1^1, a_2^2,...a_n^n\}$. If I can show $|a_n^n|<Mb_n$ where $M$ is a fixed number, then I can just use the comparison lemma to show that if $b_n$ converges to $0$, then so will $a_n^n$, but I'm not really sure how to do so.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** After a while, $|a_n|\lt \frac{1+|a|}{2}$.

Comment: I did this then raised both sides to the $nth$ power giving $a_n^n<(\frac{1+a}{2})^n$. Then $(\frac{1+a}{2})^n$ goes to zero as $n$ tends to infinity, so by the comparison lemma, $\{a_n^n\}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: That's right. The $\frac{1+|a|}{2}$ comes from using the definition of limit and letting $\epsilon=\frac{1-|a|}{2}$. I don't know whether you are expected to prove that if $|b|\lt 1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}b^n=0$. Chances are good that this has been proved already in your course.

Comment: The problem doesn't give any conditions on $b$. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a direct approach:
As $|a|<1$, there exists $0<q<1$ with $|a|<q<1$.
For almost all $n$, $|a_n|<q$ and hence $|a_n^n|<q^n\to 0$.